# How to manually add UITextField placeholder text that disappears when clicked inside textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I currently have a custom textfield so the storyboard way of adding placeholder text isn't working.  Right now I'm using this code in viewDidLoad but when I click inside the textfield the placeholder text still remains.

```
  usernameOrEmailTextField.text = "Username or email"
    usernameOrEmailTextField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Is there a way to have the text disappear when the textfield is clicked so the user can type their own info for the textfield?

Here is my custom textfield:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField{

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

//Border
self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
self.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
//Background
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)

//Text
self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
  }

}
```

I tried using .placeholder instead of .text:

```
  usernameOrEmailTextField.placeholder = "Username or email"
usernameOrEmailTextField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

but the textfield appears to be blank.

Comment: there is `placeholder` property in `UITextField` class. Did you use search?..

Comment: When I do  textField.placeholder = "Some text...", there is no placeholder text visible when on that view

Comment: What is the background colour of your view? The placeholder text is light grey.

Comment: Is there a way to change the placeholder text color

Comment: The background is a wood color

Comment: You can use the `attributedPlaceholder` if you want a custom coloured placeholder text.

Comment: How can I make the placeholder text color white by using the  attributedPlaceholder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField:)` for it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var textField: CustomTextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.placeholder = "Some text..."
  }

  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.placeholder = ""
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: It should disappear on its own though after a character is inserted, I think his sole problem is he's either using the wrong type of text box or he is setting .text not .placeholder

Comment: I do see where you are coming from though if it is meant that he wants the placeholder to go away just by selecting, not by waiting to insert a character

Comment: It's a custom textfield:

Comment: I edited my original post to include the custom textfield

Comment: This should also work for your `CustomTextField` since its inheriting from `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what was wrong.  The  `textField.placeholder = "Some text..."` does work it's just that my background was a dark color so I couldn't see the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no placeholder text option for a text view.

What you are doing is changing the text of the textfield, which doesn't go away when tapped.

IF you can, you could use a UITextField. In this case you could use textFieldName.placeholder = "Enter text", which would work.

But to answer the actual question, the way I have done this in the past is to put a UILabel overtop the UITextField and then use the delegate methods of the text view to hide / show the label when the user taps in.

Example: Hide label if user didBeginEditing text field, if didEndEditing, check if the text inside is empty, if so show the label, otherwise don't.

EDIT: To be clear, to me it seems like you are using a TextView but said TextField. Including the IBOutlet would show us for sure.